# Blog site for area51 sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, blog, stackexchange-2.0

One of the biggest factors in involving people in SO was the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) and [podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/).  It provided some idea of what the site should be, pointed out [interesting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), and generally kept me interested.  It's great for when you want to know what's going on, but don't have time to filter through things on meta.  It would make sense therefore for the various SE-2.0 sites to include a blog site for the duly elected moderators to post on.  The point of this site would not be *necessarily* to post information about technical changes, or duplicate the main blog, but instead to serve as a guiding light for the community, posting information that's on topic to the site.  It's one more way for them to succeed.

**Note:** This isn't totally fleshed out.  I welcome your suggestions.

Comment: +1, sounds dangerous!

Comment: @Shog9 It's [dangeresque](http://www.homestarrunner.com/sbemail80.html)!

Comment: +1 I'd like to see this implemented, preferably [this way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65543/146482)

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of having a blog site with authorized (elected?) users, but I would be looking for something different from what you posted.

I'd rather see people post about the topic at hand and not company information or meta information about the site.   Example of the type of post that I'd like to see for all different sites of stackexchange (including stackoverflow) : [this serverfault blog post](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/747186396/serverfault-trees).

If this were implemented I'd suggest a different subdomain to access that page.  Something like userblog.stackoverflow.com as to not conflict with the current company news which exists at blog.stackoverflow.com

I see more value in posting about the topic at hand rather than each site posting the same thing about new features in slightly different ways.

Another idea would be to let anyone write blog entries (accessible via their user page), but it only shows up on the main blog site if you have reputation above a certain threshold?  That would give yet another big reason for people to try to build their own reputation so they can get more readers.

Comment: Maybe this could be implemented as mentioned in [Redirect blog-post discussions to meta (or meta.blog)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65543/146482), i.e. by having a separate SE-site just for blogging?

Comment: I think it would be good for everyone to be able to post a blog and everyone can also tag their blogs.  Then when you click on a tag you can have another item next to stats called blog.  Could also tie into another site like you said and/or the user account.