# Redirect blog-post discussions to meta (or meta.blog)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, stack-exchange, blog

Inspired by [Jeff's answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64005/imgur-copyrighted-images-from-the-web-and-imgur-accounts/64029#64029),

> I thought this was already discussed in the comments to the blog post announcing the feature [...]

Yeah, reading the [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) is one thing, but digging through a forum-like comment-tail when we could actually use the SE engine and simply vote on the most relevant things, I ask why discuss at the blog when there is a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag here? Why not make [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) a mod-only tag for entries duplicating the blog entry (or soft-linking to its contents)?

Comment: That's a really good point.  Many of the SE users don't know about the SO blog at all.

Comment: +1 because this might get more people involved in the Meta sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really see the point of this request; the blog is the blog, and meta is meta.

1. If I want *detailed* feedback on a topic with voting from the insider community I will open it on meta.
2. If I want to broadcast a message to the wider stackexchange.com audience, I will post it as a blog entry.

In some blog entries I do both things, but generally they serve different purposes.

Comment: as I mentioned in the request, there are sometimes trails of comment leading to some new feature or other thing and it would be nice to understand their development (and maybe vote for/against it directly) without the whole noise around. I mean, re 1: You can say you don't _want_ detailed feedback and still you may get some, and then it might also be helpful for you to see votes on how serious you should take it. Re 2, why not use the Inbox for big announcments anyway?

Comment: oh well, at least there is a flashy red "new" button at the bottom indicating the age of the most recent blog post now (though I'd prefer it to vanish when I clicked it once)

Comment: But blogs are (now?) used for more things then SE announcements (many sites have their own blogs).

Answer (score 4):

An easier solution would be to disable blog comments, then re-post blog entries as a "question" on meta.

However, that's a horrible abuse of the Q&A model, so a new type of post would be required, something which doesn't allow answers and is otherwise geared for "announcements" — it would require commenting at 1 rep, for example.  You would benefit from the users of the SE site voting, responding, using notifications, etc. — even fixing typos (if they have 2k rep) in the post.  This type of post would only be needed on meta sites, and should probably be restricted to moderators/admins.

Comment: I don't think a meta.SO [discussion] is much different from what we both are basically asking for. Minor stuff like "this sucks" as comments, relevant suggestion on what to improve or "why this is really great (TM)" as answers. And as @Simon stated, meta's comment rep requirement is already 1rep

Comment: I don't see why answers can't be used, other than them being called "answers". People can comment with 1 rep on MSO.

Comment: @Simon I see we agree :)

Comment: @Simon: I was thinking of announcements on other meta sites, where you cannot comment with 1 rep.  For example, [blog.SF](http://blog.serverfault.com/) on [meta.SF](http://meta.serverfault.com/).

Comment: @Tobias: I think, when explicitly not asking a question, explicitly breaking with the Q&A model would work better than trying to jam a square peg in a round hole.  The best uses of meta.SO still ask questions, with the [discussion] tag as a necessary evil to meet the "1 required tag" requirement when the others don't apply.  The SO blog posters appreciate reactions and comments, but they are rarely asking questions, or at least that's my impression.

Comment: @Roger Pate: but how likely is someone with < 50 rep on SF to read its blog? Also, that is the _only_ example since there only are _the_ blog and SF's blog

Comment: @Tobias: So you think moderators/admins of the other sites will never want to make an announcement besides the "system message banner" — which is only a single line, doesn't allow feedback, and evaporates with no public trace?  An explicit "blog post" type would allow [other uses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44199/stack-overflow-and-gotw) that also [don't fit the Q&A model](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62697/stack-overflow-and-gotw-what-happened-with-this/62754#62754).

Comment: @Roger Pate: ok, I didn't see it from that point, but this is a different issue. I am only talking about the big blog announcing SE stuff in general, for which a migration to meta.SO would not yield these problems. But if you [feature-request] a blog-type post, I'll probably +1 it