# Minimum Reputation before site logo appears on Flair

Tags: discussion, reputation, flair, combined-flair

What is the minimum reputation required before a sites logo will appear on the combined flair?

My flair looks like this:

[image: rjstelling flair]

But I am a user on Superuser and [Apple Answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) among others. [Joel's post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/) shows examples with 7 sites, is this the maximum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the comments on the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/) about the flair, Jeff says the minimum rep for a site to be included is 200.

<sub>There are [other options](https://stackapps.com/questions/1567/stackflair-generate-flair-for-your-stackexchange-associated-accounts-now-with) if you want to work around this.</sub>

Comment: Read comments on a blog post? I just assumed it was sados and perverts ;)

Comment: @rjs this is because we don't consider a user "serious" on a site until they earn 200 rep. Dabbling doesn't count :)

Comment: @rjstelling: +1, that's my point: [Redirect blog-post discussions to meta (or meta.blog)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65543/redirect-blog-post-discussions-to-meta-or-meta-blog)