# Is the combined flair image broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair

I was trying to put my combined flair icon on my web site, but the image seems broken.

Individual site images appear and work fine.

Maybe the site just doesn't like me :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimum Reputation before site logo appears on Flair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/minimum-reputation-before-site-logo-appears-on-flair)

Comment: Now that I understand the minimum reputation it makes sense.  Maybe on the flair page where it shows the combined flair option it should mention the minimum requirement.  Might clear up that bit of confusion.

Comment: probably don't want to advertise that you have no reputation :)

Comment: self deprecation is the only form of humor that I am good at :)

Comment: @NAS, you mean another form of humor that you're bad at?

Comment: @Popular well "good" is a subjective term isn't it?

Comment: @NAS, no, because you're saying that you're good at saying you're bad... which is contradictory... never mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the combined flair only includes sites where your reputation is over 200.  None of your associated accounts meet this.  The flair needs a better way to handle this case.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65780/140548) deals with the minimum requirement.

Comment: ah ha, my lowly status foils my plans again.

Comment: Well, you could read the fine print on the answer I linked...

Answer (score 3):

We will now be showing this image

[image]

when you don't have any network accounts with 200+ reputation.

Sure beats a 404...

(note, I'm not kidding, this is really what we're going to do.)

Comment: Sure does beat the 404.