# Combined flair not found?

Tags: bug, flair, combined-flair

From any of my SE accounts, when I go to "Flair", the account specific flair is displayed correctly and its HTML source works; however the combined flair is never correctly displayed and the corresponding image is not found even if I follow the link. The link to the SE profile works though, and on that linked profile page I can clearly see all of my accounts with the right reputation.

[image]

Am I missing something?

I found [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65817/is-the-combined-flair-image-broken), but 2 more of my accounts have reputation greater than 200 so it should display the sum.

Comment: I don't know why is that, probably because of some blocks. Either way, I [see it](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/153248.png). Do you see the image after following the link?

Comment: No, I end up on a page with a derp panda saying something went wrong

Comment: The panda tried to climb the slide but fell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I can see it properly:

[image]

But as you can't see it directly for some unknown reasons, try seeing it when passed through my server:

http://justachat.freevar.com/exget.php?url=https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/153248.png

Though actually, if you go about embedding your flair somewhere, you can embed [the normal non-rerouted one](https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/153248.png), because seems that only you have the problem with not seeing it (or anyone else can't see the original flair?).

> [image]

The workaround I provided is just so as it'd be possible for you to see it :)

(As for the workaround: I have `/exget.php?url={any-url-here}` just in case I want to get something from another server and use in my codes, but javascript often doesn't allow it because cross-origin calls with it are prohibited - so I made the simple rerouter in php. Seems we can make use of it there :)

Comment: I can see both on my home PC now, that is weird. When I posted this question I was on my work computer - I only have notions of network engineering so I can't explain it, but I assume it has something to do with the network setup at work then.