# Why isn't my stackoverflow rep included in my "combined Stack Exchange" rep?

Tags: support, reputation, combined-flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimum Reputation before site logo appears on Flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65780/minimum-reputation-before-site-logo-appears-on-flair)

I noticed that only my Cross Validated and Mathematics reputation is included in my Stack Exchange network reputation, and not any other sites (such as Stack Overflow). Is that because there is some minimum threshold before they are included?

Comment: Possibly a dupe of [Minimum Reputation before site logo appears on Flair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65780)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only sites where your reputation is over 200 are included.

Your Stack Overflow reputation is 190 (at the time of writing) and hence isn't included.

Once it gets to more than 200 it will be included but there will be a delay as caches are updated.