# Combined flair hasn't been updated after more than 100 hours

Tags: support, reputation, flair, combined-flair

The [flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/410264/pacoverflow?tab=flair) for my combined Stack Exchange profiles shows 7 sites:

[image: combined flair]

But it doesn't show [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/27367/pacoverflow?tab=reputation) or [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/13812/pacoverflow?tab=reputation), and I have over 200 reputation on both of those sites.  According to the [flair page](https://stackexchange.com/users/410264/pacoverflow?tab=flair) on my network profile, the combined flair "is only updated once every 24-36 hours."  But if you look at my [Web Applications reputation history](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/27367/pacoverflow?tab=reputation), I went over 200 rep on July 27 at 19:35, which was over 101 hours ago:

[image: webapps rep history]

Also, my [Skeptics reputation history](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/13812/pacoverflow?tab=reputation) shows that I went over 200 rep on July 28 at 17:14, which was over 79 hours ago:

[image: skeptics rep history]

I found [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65890/202205) to a different flair issue that said "if you don't see it changing within 48-96 hours let us know", so I figured I'd let you know about this issue.

Comment: @gnat are you sure this is a duplicate? It doesn't say that it only takes the rep of 7 sites, just that it won't display more than 7 icons.

Comment: @Stijn part about reputation is a dupe of another question: [Why isn't my stackoverflow rep included in my “combined Stack Exchange” rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140827/why-isnt-my-stackoverflow-rep-included-in-my-combined-stack-exchange-rep)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding up all your reputation for sites over 200 comes out to 2,821 reputation, which corresponds to the 2.8k displayed.

The flair also only shows your **top seven** sites with over 200 reputation, simply because there's only room for seven. I mean, where would you expect more of them to show up?

Your flair is up-to-date and displaying correctly.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it was limited to the top 7 sites. I thought the width of the box would increase to accommodate additional sites. Or perhaps the height would increase to allow an additional row.