# Can subjective questions work on StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, subjective

I was mulling over asking this question yesterday, because in various discussions around here, people were saying "subjective can't work on StackExchange", "it wasn't designed for that", etc. Whereas, to me, the fact that StackOverflow *discourages* subjective questions doesn't mean that they *couldn't* work elsewhere.

Now [Robert Cartaino has blogged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) on this subject.

I wondered what the rest of the community makes of this. Can you see his 6 criteria working in practice?

Comment: I tried to add the subjective tag twice...

Comment: How very Meta of you...

Comment: See? That's exactly why I want [Redirect blog-post discussions to meta (or meta.blog)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65543/146482)

Comment: StackOverflow is being drowned by a massive amount of objective and specific, but mediocre questions nowadays that seeing an intelligent but subjective question is a breath of fresh air.

Comment: Well, we're applying them at programmers.se, so we'll see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Policy enforcement: time for an SO site for all the things SO isn't?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143010/policy-enforcement-time-for-an-so-site-for-all-the-things-so-isnt)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think that blog post covers the subject precisely.  It gives very specific guidelines that we'll be able to use in asking, answering and closing questions.  I'm glad they finally came out with such good documentation.  They should link to that post from the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you see his 6 criteria working in practice?

Depends on what you mean by "working". They'll get *used*, have no doubt. As fodder for arguments on edge-cases, they'll be wonderfully popular *I'm sure!*

This, in particular, I fear will be quoted too often...

> Certainly experiences inform opinions, but the best subjective questions unabashedly and unashamedly prioritize sharing actual experiences over random opinions.

I get what he's saying there. Don't just ask for "Crystal Reports sucks!" - ask *why*, and then ask for concrete descriptions of scenarios where it's failed. But obviously if you're describing an exact scenario and asking whether a specific tool works in that scenario, it's not a terribly subjective question anymore... So what I expect to arise from this are effectively "horror stories" questions... Which conflict with the anti-GTKY stance of the final guideline.

So buckle up, folks - we're in for a wild ride...