# Put site change notification as a header

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

There are big banners that are put at the top of the page for lots of events, e.g. when you get some comments or earn a new badge, or when it's your first time on the site.

When a big change is made to the operation of the site, this should be noted with a banner. You shouldn't need the insider knowledge of the "blog" link at the bottom of the page to know what's going on.

Comment: What are some examples of big changes?

Comment: @Michael, a big change would be one that people would notice immediately - like a massive change in the list of questions shown on the front page for example, as happened yesterday. Some people thought it was a bug, and I myself didn't know what to make of it until I hit the blog.

Comment: +1, possibly related: [Redirect blog-post discussions to meta (or meta.blog)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65543/146482). Also you may want to favourite [Recent feature changes on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/146482)

Comment: @Tobias, I consider meta to be insider knowledge nearly as much as the blog. You could use the site consistently without running into either one. Don't worry about me, I'm well informed, but I worry about the people who see a change and immediately create a post on SO saying "Hey it's broken!"

Comment: I think that it would be helpful although I think there should be a button so that users that would notice straight away if there was a change aren't notified if they don't want to be.